# PHP phpgraphlib Error

Tags: php

Currently i working on website using wordpress. So, i using phpgraphlib create a graph according to my **PHPMYADMIN database.**

I have a problem is when create a graph using SQL with Session variable, it show error message "graph too small or too many data points" as shown at below Example1 image.But when i create a graph using SQL with predefine value for `Username="leeyengyang"`, it generate a graph perfectly as shown in below Example image. So, i try echo the `$sql` query for the `$_SESSION['fullname'],` it shows `SELECT * FROM YY where Username= 'leeyengyang'. It should be no difference between $_SESSION['fullname']` and `'leeyengyang'`, but the graph is not display properly.

Please help.
I had attach my data from **PHPMYADMIN** , Example1 code & image, Example code & image at below.

Example1 Code:

```html
<?php
include("phpgraphlib.php");
$graph=new PHPGraphLib(550,350); 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'YY', 'YY123')
   or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     
mysql_select_db('YY_hospital') or die('Could not select database');
  
$dataArray=array();
  
//get data from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM YY where Username= '". $_SESSION['fullname']."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $salesgroup=$row["Date"];
      $count=$row["Data"];
      //add to data areray
      $dataArray[$salesgroup]=$count;
  }
}
  
//configure graph
$graph->setBackgroundColor("black");
$graph->addData($dataArray);
$graph->setBarColor('255,255,204');
$graph->setTitle('Tracking System');
$graph->setTitleColor('yellow');
$graph->setupYAxis(12, 'yellow');
$graph->setupXAxis(20, 'yellow');
$graph->setGrid(false);
$graph->setGradient('silver', 'gray');
$graph->setBarOutlineColor('white');
$graph->setTextColor('white');
$graph->setDataPoints(true);
$graph->setDataPointColor('yellow');
$graph->setLine(true);
$graph->setLineColor('yellow');
$graph->createGraph();
?>
```

Example 1 Image: http://i184.photobucket.com/albums/x184/Akasha_92/Fail_zps75bd8268.png
Example Code:

```html
<?php
include("phpgraphlib.php");
$graph=new PHPGraphLib(550,350); 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'YY', 'YY123')
   or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     
mysql_select_db('YY') or die('Could not select database');
  
$dataArray=array();
  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM YY where Username= 'LEEYENGYANG'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $salesgroup=$row["Date"];
      $count=$row["Data"];
      //add to data areray
      $dataArray[$salesgroup]=$count;
  }
}
  
//configure graph
$graph->setBackgroundColor("black");
$graph->addData($dataArray);
$graph->setBarColor('255,255,204');
$graph->setTitle('Tracking System');
$graph->setTitleColor('yellow');
$graph->setupYAxis(12, 'yellow');
$graph->setupXAxis(20, 'yellow');
$graph->setGrid(false);
$graph->setGradient('silver', 'gray');
$graph->setBarOutlineColor('white');
$graph->setTextColor('white');
$graph->setDataPoints(true);
$graph->setDataPointColor('yellow');
$graph->setLine(true);
$graph->setLineColor('yellow');
$graph->createGraph();
?>
```

Example Image: http://i184.photobucket.com/albums/x184/Akasha_92/ok_zpsbd175b29.png

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use MySQLi or PDO instead

Comment: @Raptor Be more kind. Say something like "The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Instead, use the `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO`."

Comment: @whywhy Your problem is that you are missing a `session_start();` there, on line 2.

Comment: Ismael Miguel, You are genius, Solve my problem. Thanks !!!
Thanks Raptor for the information ^.^ , Where to click Solved for this topic ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not a genius. But thank you for the compliment. Just remember to initialize the session (using `session_start();`) in every *individual* page (pages that you access but that you don't `include()` or `require()`) to avoid this kind of problem. I've made this mistake so many times that I lost track. I had to learn one day. I'm glad your problem is solved now.

Comment: To mark a question as "solved", you can answer it yourself, wait 2 days and mark it as the accepted answer. I currently don't know how this is accepted, but, optionally, you can edit and add `[solved]` to the title. Again, I've never seen this being done and don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the ession)start() at line 2 , and the problem solved. Thanks ismael

```html
<?php
session_start(); //line2
?>
```